# How to return the current page url inside a wagtail app's model.py file

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a wagtail app in which I need to return the current page's url. The code for my model.py of my app is as follows

```
import urllib

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from django.http import HttpResponse

class PageUrl(Page):
    def returnPageUrl(self):
        page_url = """ i need the page url here """
        return page_url
```

Answer (score 7):

A `Page` model has a field `url_path`. You thus can access the page URL with:

```
class PageUrl(Page):

    def returnPageUrl(self):
        return self.url_path
```

or you can make use of [**`full_url`**](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.6.2/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.full_url) to obtain the full url (including the hostname, etc.):

```
class PageUrl(Page):

    def returnPageUrl(self):
        return self.full_url
```

That being said, since it is already a field, I think there is not much use to define an extra method for this.

Comment: thanks @willem that works and it returns with the slug. is it possible to get the full url with page id or as you mentioned is there any field like page_id  like url_path .. apologies for the newbie question

Comment: @LalasM: then you can use `.full_url`.